# How can I upload two images in a form to 2 different directories in django?

Tags: django

model:

```
class Model1(models.Model):
    ...
    pic1 = models.ImageField()
    pic2 = models.ImageField()
```

How can I upload two images in a form to 2 different directories in django? For example, pic1 in MEDIA_ROOT/pic1/ and pic2 in MEDIA_ROOT/pic2/?

I have read the django document, but I can't find the answer with upload_to argument of FileField.

updated: Sorry to mention, when uploadding the images to 2 different directories, how can I rename them respectively? pic1 will be saved to  MEDIA_ROOT/pic1/year-month-day-original_name.jpg and pic2 to MEDIA_ROOT/pic2/year-month-day-original_name.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**models.py**

```
def get_pic1_path(instance, filename):
    return new_path(path="pic1", filename)

def get_pic2_path(instance, filename):
    return new_path(path="pic2", filename)

def new_path(path, filename):
    today = date.now()
    today_path = today.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    image_path = "{0}-{1}".format(today_path, filename)
    return os.path.join(path, image_path)

class Model1(models.Model):
    ...
    pic1 = models.CustomImageField(upload_to=get_pic1_path)
    pic2 = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_pic2_path)
```

**views.py**

```
...
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = Model1Form(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            image = Model1.objects.create()
            pic1 = request.FILES['pic1']
            pic2 = request.FILES['pic2']

            image.pic1.save(pic1.name, image_file)
            image.pic2.save(pic2.name, image_file)
...
```

Comment: Think this is what OP is looking for. +1 from me.

Answer (score 1):

I think I must have misunderstood your question. Surely this does exactly what you're describing -

```
class Model1(models.Model):
    ...
    pic1 = models.ImageField(upload_to="pic1")
    pic2 = models.ImageField(upload_to="pic2")
```

The file in the `pic1` field will be uploaded to MEDIA_ROOT/pic1/ and the file in the `pic2` field will be uploaded to MEDIA_ROOT/pic2/.

**UPDATE**

Have a look at the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to) on the upload_to parameter - you can pass it a function to create the path dynamically, as described in Catherines answer.

I know it's not quite what you're planning, but if you wanted something super simple to organise your files, then it's worth noting that you can also use [strftime](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/time.html#time.strftime) notation in the `upload_to` parameter.

```
pic1 = models.ImageField(upload_to='pic1/%Y/%m/%d')
```

This would give you a path like - `/path/to/media_root/pic1/2013/03/11/filename.jpg`

Comment: Sorry to mention, when uploadding the images to 2 different directories, how can I rename them respectively? e.g pic1 to MEDIA_ROOT/pic1/year-month-day-original_name.jpg and pic2 to MEDIA_ROOT/pic2/year-month-day-origina2_name.jpg